# In MongoDB, What is the time complexity of this query?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql, time-complexity

There is a table of M rows, with a column which records the date and time the row was updated and a numeric column to record the `SCORE` of this row.

QUERY:

Find the X most recently updated rows and compute the average `SCORE`.

EDITED:

Further, let's break it up into 2 querys:

1. Find the X most recently updated rows.
2. Compute the average `SCORE` of the rows returned in `1`.

What is the time-complexity of query 1 and query 2?

Comment: If you have an index on the (for example) `updateTime` field, then finding the X most recently update rows is a covered

Comment: What does "a covered" mean?

Comment: Editing timeout; apols.   A covered query is one where the information includes only the index.   So an index on `updateTime` where the query is "last X updated items" is as fast as the walk of the b-tree index.

Comment: So #1 goes very fast.  If X most recently updated rows is << than total rows, then computing the average `SCORE` will still be very fast.   All in all , def less than `O(N)`.